# Correct word useage

Tags: word-usage, language-evolution

English is my native tongue, yet I am often confused by word usage in the language. An example of this would be the difference between "clothing" and "clothes" used as nouns.

For example, a store that sells clothing (or clothes) can be referred to as either a "clothing store," or a "clothes store." They are interchangeable, and from sheer exposure, I perceive that neither one is preferable or more accurate, except that perhaps using the term "clothes store" might be thought of as a more casual term than "clothing store."

The thing is, if there is no difference, and I don't think there is, how did this redundancy come about and why does it persist? Seems silly and has to be confounding for anyone trying to learn English.

Then, even more confusing is the gerund, "clothing": to clothe something/someone/oneself. But, though "clothes" can also be use as a verb: "He clothes the poor," there is no such gerund as "clothesing."

Comment: The short answer is: English isn’t algebra. It isn’t designed. It certainly isn’t designed to make it easy for non-native speakers to learn! It is a messy, inconsistent, redundant, organic, closed-form-proof agglomeration of the expressed opinions of millions and millions of individual speakers with different needs and aims over literal centuries, going on a millennium now. Even if we had the mad idea that it should be some pure and crystalline device, there is no one to appeal to about defects, and even if there were, such repairs would not stick, and new tears would appear. It’s wonderful.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. English is an ever evolving language for sure. It's interesting to have lived long enough to witness the formation of new "English" words, and a little sad to see some graceful ones fall out of use.

Comment: @KJO It meant rents. New flaws.

Comment: Gerund: "he was obsessed with his clothing of the poor." Tricky, because if I use *the* instead of *his*, it's possible to read "clothing" as purely a noun rather than having a verb sense. PS to form a gerund, we take the bare infinitive and add "ing": *clothe* + -*ing* = *clothing*. We never use the 3rd person indicative to form the gerund.

Comment: To add to the wisdom of the others: words are funny.  Consider “paint”.  It’s a noun (which can be used attributively: “paint job”, “paint store”, etc., and in portmanteaux like “paintbrush”) and also a verb (so “painting” is a gerund).  But ***a*** painting is a work of art.  Similarly, “dwell” is a verb (so “dwelling” is a gerund), but ***a*** dwelling is a residence.

Comment: The verb in 'he clothes the poor' is **to clothe**. 'Clothes' is the present tense, third person singular, 'clothing' is the gerund.

Comment: @Scott Great expansion of the topic. Clothes and clothing were around for centuries prior to any 'store' in which to buy them. Most store fronts, other than bakeries, butchers and tailors trades, were general stores with a wide range of merchandise. Only after the Industrial Revolution did stores begin to become outlets of manufactured products. Which break down to the these two words being used in identifying the store's distinctive product, which could be referred to as either clothing, or clothes.